# problem with date conversion sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow

The following Workflow is returning the wrong date time.  Can you help explain why and how to fix it?

1. Set Variable:CurrentDay to Today
2. Then Set Time as 00:00 for Variable:CurrentDay (Output to Variable:CurrentDay)
3. Then Set Variable:DateInSeconds to Variable:CurrentDay
4. Then Set Variable:ConvertedSecondsToDate to Variable:DateInSeconds

This is only a conversion Workflow and should result in Variable:CurrentDay = Variable:ConvertedSecondsToDate

But What I get returned is:
  Variable:CurrentDay = 2/20/2015 12:00 AM
  Variable:ConvertedSecondsToDate = 2/19/2015 7:00 PM

I am using SharePoint Designer 2010. the workflow variables are:
 CurrentDay as DateTime, 
 ConvertedSecondsToDate as DateTime, 
 DateInSeconds as number(Double)

the statement #3 that assigns CurrentDay to DateInSeconds outputs CurrentDay to "Number of Seconds from 00:00:00 1/1/1900"

I cannot help but think it is a conversion error related to the leap seconds which on 2/20/2015 has us a little more than 3/4 of a leap day ahead of the datetime on our clocks.  We will adjust for a full leap day next year.  This seems to correspond well with  the 'little more than 3/4 of a day offset" that the resulting 7:00 PM time part seems to represent when seconds are converted to date.  But even that is questionable as I would expect to see an offset result of date+19hrs rather than date-1day+19hrs, but computer date start points and math are as varied as colors in a crayon box.  Hence this question to the experts.

Comment: How you are adding the time part in step 2?
It is possible, here you are clearing both date and time.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Anir.  Step 2 is a standard Workflow statement that allows us to modify the time portion only on a date/time field or variable.  In this case I am using it to ensure that my captured date is whole date only as it is dropping off the hhmmss in the value by way of the time setting to "00:00".  This statement is correctly returning 2/20/2015 12:00 AM.

Comment: I think I found the cause.  Please verify if you know for sure.  I am in the Eastern time zone of the USA which is  UTC-5.  The 7:00 PM time part returned is also UTC-5.  Which means my adjustment of dropping off hhmmss to 12:00 AM set my time value back 5 hours there returned the -5 hour offset.  Experts... is that what is happening?  If so, it is nice to know but then I have a different problem. How do I write a workflow that performs date math on UTC values then return the result in the appropriate time zone?